# How to create/assign properties to graphical objects?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Currently, I'm writing a simple draw application where it draws lines, ellipse and etc on canvas. However, this is just the start and I need to allow end user to change properties of each graphical object. Let's say line have color attribute or coordination parameters that should change.

A few things to add:

1. WPF Application
2. C#
3. XML to store information

I will appreciate it if experts give me some ideas and heads up on how to create/assign properties to objects.

Thanks in advance.

ak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create instances of the [`Shape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.aspx#inheritanceContinued) classes and use those objects' properties to set things like color.  You'll need to create your interface allowing the user to do this.  You can use the [`XamlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.aspx) and [`XamlReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader) classes to serialize your info.

Comment: Thanks please correct me if I'm wrong, so I have to create classes (inherited from  Shape class) e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.aspx and then write those properties into XML file as while serialization. Correct me if I'm wrong.  Thank you.

Comment: You have to create *instances* of classes inherited from Shape.  There are a number of these built-in, like Ellipse, Line, and Rectangle.  Sounds like you've got the right general idea, though.